# I have found a bug in the Microsoft Dynamics CRM SDK - how and where to report?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, xrm

So, I believe I have found a bug in the Microsoft.Xrm.Client.dll which is shipped as part of the Microsoft Dynamics CRM SDK.

My question is, is there a correct procedure for reporting bugs with the SDK and what is it?

At the moment I have posted something here: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/144464.aspx but I am not sure this is the correct place?

Comment: @JamesWood - the Microsoft.Xrm.Client.dll doesn't work correctly when its running from the GAC. Follow my link on the question for further info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Product support is available [direct from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/product-support.aspx), with different ontact points if this is an on-premises installation, CRM Online, or for developers with an MSDN subscription.

Comment: Thank you, I believe this is the route I will have to go down, the connect site seems to be for feature suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Official place for bugs in Microsoft products is Microsoft Connect site.

Go to [http://connect.microsoft.com/directory/?keywords=dynamics+crm](http://connect.microsoft.com/directory/?keywords=dynamics%20crm), press "Join" link in the corresponding line.